# pyplot colormap and bar not corresponding to values

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar, colormap

Some reasons far beyond my comprehension, I've set two different heatmaps and whilst one works perfectly fine, the second one maps several different colors to the same z number (0, for example), and the colorbar is totally reversed.

So, my first heatmap is this:

[image]

and the code for it's generation is:

```
data = mcs(n,k)         # the monte carlo simulation that returns my 2d numpy array

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap="inferno")

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(data)))

ax.set_xticklabels(data.index)
ax.set_yticklabels(data.columns)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

for i in range(len(data.index)):
    for j in range(len(data.columns)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, f"{int(data[i+1][j+1]):2}%",
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w")

ax.set_title("Percentage of success on a contested check")
ax.set_xlabel("Attacker poll size")
ax.set_ylabel("Defender pool size")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But then I tried a second heatmap, created by a very similar function, and with a colorbar. But the result was very different...

[image]

And the code:

```
data = mcs_fixed(n, k)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap="viridis")
cb = plt.colorbar(im)


ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(data)))

ax.set_xticklabels(data.index)
ax.set_yticklabels(data.columns)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

for i in range(len(data.index)):
    for j in range(len(data.columns)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, f"{int(data[i+1][j+1]):2}%",
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w")

ax.set_title("Percentage of success on a skill check")
ax.set_xlabel("Challenger poll size")
ax.set_ylabel("Established difficulty")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Why are some many zeroes mapped to different colors, and the map makes no sense at all? And why is the Colorbar colors inverted? I tried reversing the colorbar y-axis, but it reverses both the colors AND the numbers, thus not solving the problem.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I TOTALLY FORGOT TO SAY, the data being imported is a pandas Dataframe. I changed the data to a list, and the Colorbar worked wonderfully. The axes got inverted, though...

**EDIT 2:** Here's a small sample of data to reproduce the results.

```
test_case = [[40.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [64.0, 19.0, 3.0, 0.0],
         [78.0, 39.0, 15.0, 4.0],
         [88.0, 55.0, 25.0, 4.0]]

data = pd.DataFrame(test_case)
data.index += 1
data.columns += 1
```

Comment: Not reproducible on my end. Of course, I had to simulate your input because it is not described. But both codes behaved as expected, and it is not directly clear why the second code should behave differently. BTW, imshow has the keyword `origin="lower"`.

Comment: There could be multiple things here. First, as pointed by @Mr. T, you should check the short [guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) available in the doc. Second, I would recommend to avoid mixing calls to `ax` and `plt` after you have called `subplots`. You can just use `ax`, or `fig`. Also, if both figures exist at the same time, providing `num` to `subplots` is recommended. Finally, but I think it is unlikely, any chance for a transpose somewhere?

Comment: Guys, sorry, I forgot to tell'ya, the data being inputted is a pandas DataFrame.
I believe the heatmap color difference is just normal for the configuration, and the inverted colorbar is some weird interpretation of DataFrame data.

Comment: To explain shortly: test 1 makes 2 users roll n 10-sided dice and counts how many times each user scored a 7 or more, them compares who got more successes. Ties count as a defense win. Test 2 makes a user roll n 10-sided dice and compares how many 7+ he has against a given difficulty. Shall I share the entire code?

Comment: No. It is only relevant what data structure is returned, not how it was generated. So, you should include a sample pandas df that reproduces the unwanted behavior. Preferentially much smaller than the df used in your figure. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted question, I'm still new to StackOverflow. Thanks for the tips. I've added a second Edit with some (hopefully) reproducible data. I guess the different colors attached to the same value on colormap are just the expected behaviour, but what about the inverted Colorbar?

Comment: Okay now I can reproduce it. Your rows and columns are mixed up (i and j, data.index and data.columns). That's why you label them wrongly giving the impression that the colorbar is inverted. You do not notice that if the matrix is symmetric. Try a df that has different lengths of rows and columns to get better grip of this problem - for instance `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data))), ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(data)))` covers this problem also up because you assume the rows and columns have equal lengths.

Comment: You even noticed that problem yourself without realizing `...The axes got inverted, though... `.

Comment: Damn it, this piece "text = ax.text(j, i,..." I retrieved from the internet without closely inspecting. I found it weird that it was j,i, but thought I was wrong to disbelieve it. Now I see the problem was not the colorbar, but the labels! thank you so much.

Comment: I was deceived by the symmetric nature of your input for some time as well. Glad this is solved. Good luck with your project.